# How to get full url of referring links

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Assume there a page containing a link to my site and the url for this referring page was this:

http://source.com/referral_path/topic.php?t=123

In google analytics it would display as this:

- **ga:source**: source.com
- **ga:referral_path**: /referral_path/topic.php

I recall long ago there was a switch/setting which would control whether the **t=123** (i.e. query parameters) would be included as part of the referral_path or not.  Is this correct?  And if it is how do I control it.

Answer (score 3):

The only setting GA has for query parameters is the search query params. [Setting Up Site Search for a Profile](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012264&topic=1031951&ctx=topic)

For the full URL you still should apply a filter.

[View Full Page URL In Reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012243)

Also see: [Full referrer URL in Google Analytics reports](http://blog.yjl.im/2012/03/full-referrer-url-in-google-analytics.html)